# redux export in component where class already exported

Tags: react-native, react-redux, export, dispatcher

I have a react-native component class defined as the export:

```
export default class Splash extends React.Component {
```

I want to connect the Splash class to the redux store so that I get the redux state in the props (or did I misunderstand the concept?) and so that I can dispatch actions via the setState methods. I have the `mapStateToProps` and the `mapDispatchToProps` defined in the Splash.js (or did I get things wrong here too?)

So I want to do

```
export default reduxConnect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Splash);
```

But it is already exported. Should I change one of the `export` lines?  Do I need to use the reduxConnect to get the props with the state, and to use my setState dispatcher methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the following way

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class Splash extends React.Component {
  ... rest of the code
  ... dispatch by referencing props from the connector
}

const mapStateToProps = state = ({
   ... bind props to the store values here
})

 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch = ({
   ... dispatch the actions here
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Splash)
```

I suggest you to checkout the examples at the docs [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md)

Comment: I saw those examples, but wasn't sure if the "main" export would be lost when I change it.

Comment: Ok, I meant that you can checkout examples on the usage of `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` usage.